# Uninstall a product from powershell

Tags: powershell, guid, uninstallation

How to uninstall a product using the guid of the product

I tried this

```
msiexec /x {guid}
```

But i cant uninstall the product

It worked fine when i use

```
Wmic product where identifyingnumber={guid} call uninstall
```

Comment: Did you put the product guid? Or did you literally type "guid"?

Comment: The GUID must be in curly brackets (`msiexec /x "{########-####-####-####-############}"`). If that doesn't help you need to provide more information. Do you get an error? If so, what does it say? Did you run the command with logging enabled (`/l*v logfile`)?

Comment: I used the exact guid with brackets tooo

Comment: Could you please answer the rest of Ansgar Wiechers' questions?

Comment: I just got the popup which usually appears when the parameters to msiexec is given wrongly. I dont get any errors except that

Comment: Please show the exact command and error message. Also try running the command with logging enabled and post the logfile as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$WMI = Get-WmiObject win32_product -Filter 'IdentifyingNumber = "{guid}"'
$WMI.Uninstall()
```

Comment: This does not work for per-user software installed by other users.

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote the argument. Note that PowerShell uses braces as part of its syntax (to define script blocks), so passing them to a native command does ... unexpected things (from the native command's perspective):

```
PS Home:\> args {foo}
argv[0] = H:\Batches\args.cmd
argv[1] = -encodedCommand
argv[2] = ZgBvAG8A
argv[3] = -inputFormat
argv[4] = xml
argv[5] = -outputFormat
argv[6] = text
```

PowerShell apparently tries to support calling `powershell { statements }` in a way that won't break. And in the process causes lots of unexpected input to native commands that don't happen to be PowerShell.

Note that quoting solves this:

```
PS Home:\> args '{foo}'
argv[0] = H:\Batches\args.cmd
argv[1] = {foo}
```

Also there's the way via WMI that [Avshalom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34751126/73070) mentions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ComputerName = Read-Host "Computer Name"
$Program= Read-Host "Program"
$apps = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $ComputerName | where name -Like "$Program*"
$index = 0

foreach ($app in $apps){
  $index++
  $index
  $app

}

$uninstallIndex = Read-Host "Please enter the number you want to uninstall"

$apps[$uninstallIndex-1].uninstall()

$apps = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $ComputerName |
where name -Like "$Program*"

foreach ($app in $apps){
  $index++
  $index
  $app

}
```